# Table with dynamic content ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, setstate

I am trying to render a table with dynamic content consisting of array of objects with Show More/ Show Less functionality.

While I am able to display the dynamic content, I am not able to bring in Show More/ Show less toggle. Basically `Show More` should show up when the number of items are greater than 3 and it should append the rest of items to the first three items. `Show Less` should be able to hide the items and show only first three

Help would be appreciated.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-3kpp5?file=/src/Table.js

Approach that I have tried

```
import * as React from "react";

class Table extends React.Component {
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      const { name, value } = item;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    let header = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: What have you tried so far for the show more/less functionality? Looks like this code is for showing all rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, I added a state named showLess to manage how the table should be displayed

```js
import * as React from "react";

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showLess: true
    }
  }
  renderTableData = () => {
    return this.props.data.map((item, index) => {
      // If it's show less, then it should show only 3 rows, the others we will return null
      if (this.state.showLess && index > 2) return null; 
      const { name, value } = item;
      return (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    });
  };

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    let header = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  toggleShowLess = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      showLess: !prevState.showLess
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
            <a href="#" onClick={this.toggleShowLess}>
              {this.state.showLess ? 'Show More' : 'Show Less'}
            </a>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch! If you're curious to play with an almost identical version of this, see https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-hebyn?file=/src/Table.js

Comment: Hearing you say that made my day :)

Comment: Thank you both :)

Comment: I'd suggest you to follow @Jacob 's solution as it looks cleaner during the table renderer as he managed to slice the array before calling .map and return <tr> elements.

Comment: How can I print the values dynamically,`<td>{name}</td>
          <td>{value}</td>` Like basically we are hardcoding name and value

Comment: Basically you get the name and value from item which was iterated from props.data. So you can put anything you want into the array of object and use it. (Not sure if this answers your question...)

Answer (score 0):

added and handled this state : 
**this.state = {
      showMore:false,
      showing:DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ELEMS_TO_SHOW
    }**

```
import * as React from "react";

const DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ELEMS_TO_SHOW  = 3;
class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showMore:false,
      showing:DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ELEMS_TO_SHOW
    }
  }
  renderTableData = () => {
    const {data} = this.props;
    const {showing} = this.state;
    let out = []
    for(let i = 0; i<showing;i+=1){
      const { name, value } = data[i];
      out.push(( <tr key={i}>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{value}</td>
      </tr>))
    }
    return out;
  };

  renderTableHeader = () => {
    let header = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return header.map((key, index) => {
      return <th key={index}>{key.toUpperCase()}</th>;
    });
  };

  setShownTableData = () =>{
    const {showing,showMore} = this.state;;
    const {data} = this.props;
    this.setState({showMore:!showMore,
      showing: showing === DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ELEMS_TO_SHOW ? data.length:DEFAULT_NUMBER_OF_ELEMS_TO_SHOW});

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          <tbody>
            <tr>{this.renderTableHeader()}</tr>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div onClick={()=>this.setShownTableData()}>{this.state.showMore ? "Show more":"Show Less"}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-dp21g?file=/src/Table.js